# com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, docker-compose

I have a problem when i try to run my api container that should connect to the db container.

The problem should be appearing when building the project or creating the image, because if i just run the project it successfully connect every time to the container.

Here i have my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11
RUN mkdir -p /app/
ADD build/libs/core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Also here the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  book-catalog-db:
    container_name: mysqlbc
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - ./proyecto/sql-data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    hostname: localhost
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
  book-catalog-angular:
    container_name: angularbc
    image: book-catalog-client:latest
    volumes:
     - ./proyecto/web-assets:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets
    ports:
     - 4200:80
  book-catalog-api:
    container_name: apibc
    image: coreapi:latest
    ports:
     - 8080:8080
```

I hope i get an answer fast since i dont have much time.
Good day to everyone!

i tried some things of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

Comment: What did you use as the hostname to the database server? You need to use the hostname defined in the docker-compose file (`mysqlbc`) to connect between containers, and make sure the containers are on the same network, and that the Java application depends on the database.

Comment: It could also be that the hostname is `book-catalog-db`, I always forget if docker-compose uses the container-name or not.

Comment: maybe it would work with container-name as hostname, but it doesnt work with my defined hostname 'localhost'

Comment: i just saw that i have to use service name as hostname, you were right when you said hostname may be 'book-catalog-db'

Answer (score -1):

ok, so i used

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mysqlbc
```

i got ip address from mysql container and i changed ip address on project built image,
NOW IT WORKS

Comment: You need to use the hostname defined in the docker-compose file, `mysqlbc`.

Comment: it is localhost, but didnt work with it

Comment: It is not localhost from the perspective of the other container.